# Writing data to nextion display make interrupt on stepper motor

Tags: arduino, milliseconds, stepper, nextion

I want to read temp from two max6675 and print on nextion display and at the same time stepper motor working as well , but the problem is writing data to nextion make interrupt on stepper motor , can anyone help me ?

```
#include <Stepper.h>
#include "EasyNextionLibrary.h" 
#include "max6675.h"


const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;  // change this to fit the number of steps per revolution
// for your motor

const int REFRESH_TIME = 100;           
unsigned long refresh_timer = millis();  



float dtempc = 0.0f;
float dtempf = 0.0f;
float btempc = 0.0f;
float btempf = 0.0f;


//============Drum Pin Temp digital pin in atmega============
int thermoDO = 4; 
int thermoCS = 5; 
int thermoCLK = 6; 
int thermoDO1 = 7; 
int thermoCS1 = 8; 
int thermoCLK1 = 9; 


EasyNex myNex(Serial); 
MAX6675 thermocouple(thermoCLK, thermoCS, thermoDO);
MAX6675 thermocouple1(thermoCLK1, thermoCS1, thermoDO1);



// initialize the stepper library on pins 8 through 11:
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 10, 11, 12, 13);

int stepCount = 0;  // number of steps the motor has taken

void setup() {
  // nothing to do inside the setup
  myNex.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {

  myNex.NextionListen();
  // read the sensor value:
  int sensorReading = analogRead(A0);
  // map it to a range from 0 to 100:
  int motorSpeed = map(sensorReading, 0, 1023, 0, 100);
  // set the motor speed:
  if (motorSpeed > 0) {
    myStepper.setSpeed(motorSpeed);
    // step 1/100 of a revolution:
    myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution / 100);
  }
  printonnextion();
  
}

void printonnextion(){

    if((millis()-refresh_timer) > REFRESH_TIME)
  {
    dtempc = thermocouple.readCelsius();
    dtempf = thermocouple.readFahrenheit();
    btempc = thermocouple1.readCelsius();
    btempf = thermocouple1.readFahrenheit();
    myNex.writeStr("dtempc.txt", String(dtempc)+"C"); 
    myNex.writeStr("dtempf.txt", String(dtempf)+"F"); 
    myNex.writeStr("btempc.txt", String(btempc)+"C"); 
    myNex.writeStr("btempf.txt", String(btempf)+"F");  
    myNex.writeNum("drumtemp.val", dtempc);
    myNex.writeNum("beantemp.val", btempc);
   
    
    refresh_timer = millis();  
    
  } 

  }
```

but the problem is writing data to nextion make interrupt on stepper motor , can anyone help me ?

Comment: you are calling `myStepper.step()` in the loop function without any control of the timing. This will call the function millions of times per second. Your stepper will never work like this. You need to call step at intervals long enough to give the motor enough time to move.

Comment: stepper motor work prefect if i ignore millis() function , that the problem millis function make interrupt then your comment not helping

Comment: But how can you know how many steps you have moved? You telling the stepper to move one step millions of times per second, so the motor will do the best it can. You are basically using a stepper motor as a DC motor as far as I can tell, without any feedback on the number of steps made.

Comment: that is true , i like stepper motor work like dc motor and communication with nextion , but each time data transfer to nextion display motor has interrupt and if i tell the motor for example 500 step move the data is not transfer till the motor work done , i want these two option work together at the same time